# How to create .cab file from .exe file to install from web page?

Tags: c++, .net, activex, cab

I have .exe file to install an activeX control.
And now I want to create a .cab file to install that activeX control from web page.
How can I do that?
For ex an expected result: when I visit the web page and it prompts to me to install and I click to accept installing.
Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

MakeCAB.exe!
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd583149(v=office.11).aspx

Comment: Could you make it more simple? because I create an activeX MFC control project by VS2010. And I already created install project (.exe/.msi) to install this activeX control (it works). And now I want to create a cab project in VS2010 also to install this activeX control on web page, and create a web page to put some html code in its to install activeX control. => But I don't know I create cab file wrongly or put embed code in html page wrongly? => I cannot install by cab file from web page.